# poor quality export of still images from premiere

Tags: video, premiere, file-formats, codec

This is the actual **source image** to a video track in Premiere (a PNG):
[image: decentqualityinput]

With no resizing whatsoever, and .flv output, this is a **resultant frame** from the exported video:
[image: poorqualityoutput]

#### How could I improve the output quality, especially the text?

What settings should I use

- I've tried to max out pretty much everything in the FLV export settings.
- And now I moved to MP4 output with H.264 encoding, but still get poor quality stills.
- Here are the MP4 Export settings, what should I change?

[image: MP4-poor]

#### Solution

Inspired from the answers, turns out that have to set the source to Progressive when creating a New Sequence (instead of Fields: Upper)

- this is why I did not get better results whatever my configuration once I had created a sequence with Fields set to Upper
- and this is why the following settings for my next project, yielded good stills

  - although also using higher resolution, so not sure high that plays into the test results
  - H.264 / MP4 Export settings otherwise the same

[image: ProgressiveFields]

Comment: Is the input source a set of PNGs? Any video footage involved? If not, try setting your sequence to 'Progressive'. As per the settings screencap, it's Upper field first right now.

Comment: @Mulvya it is Progressive already and greyed out (Field Order in screenshot); the source is a set of PNGs in one track (intermittent slides) and video below. I've also set video transitions to the PNGs (Cube in, Curtain out), but no other effects.

Comment: @Mulvya and in the actual Sequence Settings the Fields is greyed out too, and set at "Upper Field First"
 & tried to export without any effects just now, still poor quality stills.

Comment: Would give a +100 if I could.  I've been battling a similar problem for months, and this explained what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks more like a 'field' from the video, rather than a frame -- jagged diagonals are the tell.

If your video is interlaced, you may only get half the vertical resolution in a still, unless you specifically set it to output a full frame. Check the export settings.

Comment: sorry for the delay and thanks for the answer - im afraid i dont know how to translate your advice into specific settings though, so i have edited the question to show you what settings i use (that produce poor stills still)

Comment: found the settings needed now, please see final edit. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with image quality for a 4K video I was trying to produce. I found that for my situation the image was always very blurry upon an export, so I had to change the Format and Preset. A very nice 4K format that enabled my images to turn out crispy is the *H.264* which is quite widely used, and already has a built in default *YouTube 2160p 4K* preset which works well. Once you select this you can compare how the output will look against the source formatting by switching between *Source* and *Output*. Eventually, you can tune the default preset and make your own in order to get a nice 4K video out of the application.

[image]